# What force keeps electrons in their orbitals and not collapse into the positively charged nucleus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

I know about quantum mechanical model of an atom and how electrons behave like a standing waves and there isn't any lower level energy available for electrons below ground state energy and energy comes in discrete packets and so on...

I am just having a hard time to imagine and understand that why electrons, which are negatively charged and nucleus of an atom which is positively charged, because of protons remains separated from each other .

I mean opposite charges attract each other; so why electrons just stay in there orbitals and not collapse in the nucleus which is positively charged ?

What is that force which keeps electrons in their orbitals and thus overcome the attractive force which is being applied by the protons ?

Comment: The electromagnetic force - they *are* collapsed into the positively charged nucleus. Quantum mechanics just specifies they collapse in a special way.

Comment: It's worth note that an attractive force is not sufficient to imply collapse must happen anyway - the obvious counterexample is planetary orbits. It turns out this isn't sufficient to describe electrons, though.

Comment: you have a complete answer here [Zoom in on Atom or Unknown Physics of Short Distances](https://vladimirkalitvianski.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/zoom-in-atom-or-unknown-physics-of-short-distances/) , a link provided by the author for the [positronium](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166624/size-of-positronium)

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20003/why-dont-electrons-crash-into-the-nuclei-they-orbit? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9415/why-do-electrons-occupy-the-space-around-nuclei-and-not-collide-with-them? and many others. But it might also be worth noticing that the 1s orbital has it's maximum probability in the nucleus.

Comment: So, have you ever heard of [Uncertainty Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)?

Comment: Check John Rennie's answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88443/36790).

Answer (score -1):

It’s all about the electromagnetic force.

I’ll give the answer in two ways-
1- Imagine a satellite. It also revolves around the earth and is also attracted by the earth but it does not fall towards it. WHY? Because the earth does ZERO work on it.

2- The uncertainty principle. IF the electron comes closer to the nucleus ( i mean really close ) then it’s position will be known and thus not it’s velocity, it will fly apart from it.

PS- this is just a ‘raw’ answer, if you want to read in somewhat detail have a look - http://www.chem1.com/acad/webtut/atomic/WhyTheElectron.html